# Servidor no puede resolver ningún nombre de dominio

Tags: linux, debian, debian-9

Hoy me topé con un error y es que el servidor comenzó a presentar fallas al tratar de hacer peticiones a servidores externos. En mi caso el quise hacer un **git pull origin master** para descargar cambios de un repositorio central y me marcaba un error como este:

```
fatal: unable to access 'http://git.mydomain.com/root/proyecto.git': could not resolve host git.mydomain.com
```

Pensé que podía ser que subdominio habia dejado de funcionar pero no, porque yo podía acceder desde el navegador a ese subdominio que tiene instalado `gitlab`

Luego empecé a hacer más pruebas como un `curl` a **google.com**

```
> curl -v google.com
* Rebuilt URL to: google.com/
* Could not resolve host: google.com
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com
```

Entonces pensé que quizás el servidor no tenía acceso a internet pero puedo hacer un `ping` a internet por IP, por ejemplo 8.8.8.8

```
> ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=20.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=19.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=20.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=19.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=53 time=20.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=53 time=19.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=53 time=19.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=53 time=19.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=9 ttl=53 time=19.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=10 ttl=53 time=19.0 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9012ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.021/19.635/20.672/0.603 ms
```

Para que pueda hacer `ping` correctamente el servidor debería tener internet entonces no entiendo que puede estar pasando. ¿Alguna explicación para ésto?

Puedo hacer ping correctamente, pero no puedo hacer peticiones a los dominios.

Comment: El servidor DNS configurado en tu equipo no funciona, no responde, no está disponible o algo por el estilo. Configura la interfaz de red de tu servidor para que use un DNS válido y funcionará

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En [debian](https://debian.org), [ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) y derivados los [servidores nombres (D](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_nombres_de_dominio)NS) se especifican en el archivo **/etc/resolv.conf**

Si editas el archivo con lo siguiente y te funciona ese era el problema.

```
sudo echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

De todas formas una vez te funciona configura bien tu gestor de red, pues son los gestores de red los que habitualmente configuran dinámicamente el archivo **/etc/resolv.conf**.

Comment: Gracias, esto ya me habilito el poder hacer el curl a google.com asi mismo me dejo hacer al servidor de git